# Android Studio removes backslashes in front of apostrophe and then complains about missing backslashes

Tags: android-studio, escaping, backslash

I'm unable to compile my project due to the problem described in the title. I have a resource file with many strings, and Italian uses a lot of apostrophes in articles.

There are no double apostrophes with text inside (i.e. `'text'`), all of them are single apostrophe (i. e. `l'amico`). All of them are correctly escaped with a backslash. Example:

```
<string-array name="cards">
    <item>Un\'indescrivibile solitudine.</item>
</string-array>
```

When I click on run, it first removes all the backslahes, then it fails saying that I have unescaped apostrophes in my resource file.

I tried to clean and rebuild, but it keeps doing the same.

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.1.

Comment: can u put the full string with tag

Comment: @LahiruPinto Added an example. I have many more strings in my array.

Comment: make sure the apostrophe 's char is correct coz when u copy from article the char value might be diff.
ex : remove all the single quotes and add it manually to make sure

Comment: @LahiruPinto all those strings have been added manually, I didn't copy paste them.

Comment: i created a new project and copied this string tag.
it is building and runing without a prob in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39345557/1433971 .

The problem is that when Android Studio finds the error in the string, it opens a `value.xml` file which it uses during the build process. I didn't notice it wasn't opening the actual file with the error and there's no reason to modify the `value.xml` file as it is rebuilt from your actual resource file (which is unchanged).