# Why is this error: "Error:(18, 39) String types not allowed (at 'australia_marginEnd' with value '8dp"')." coming every single time?

Tags: android

I accidentally added a double quote (") at the end of a value in my dimens.xml file. I tried to fix it by removing those double quotes from those lines of code. I even tried removing the whole file, but after restarting Android Studio, whenever the Gradle build finishes, it automatically adds up where it was.

[Errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glJ9n.png)

> Error:(18, 39) String types not allowed (at 'australia_marginEnd' with
>   value '8dp"'). Error:(18, 39) String types not allowed (at
>   'australia_marginEnd' with value '8dp"'). Error:Execution failed for
>   task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

[Lines of code where I'm getting errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MRAU.png)

```
<dimen name="australia_marginBottom">8dp</dimen>
<dimen name="australia_marginEnd">8dp"</dimen>
<dimen name="australia_marginLeft">8dp"</dimen>
<dimen name="australia_marginRight">8dp"</dimen>
<dimen name="australia_marginStart">8dp"</dimen>
<dimen name="australia_marginTop">256dp</dimen>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code directly in the question.  Indent code with four spaces or more.

Comment: clean it... so it will work

Comment: Tim, I did what you said.

Comment: Milad it didn't work.

Comment: it seems you have deleted (") from a generated file! delete it from which file that you have created for project manually.

Comment: Thank you, Milad! It just worked. You're right, I didn't remove it from the project file. I was foolishly trying to delete the generated file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing " from you code ,

Clean your Code so that new R file generate and than Build again 
hope it helps .

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Actually, whenever Gradle comes to use, it regenerates the previous code. So, I think it has something to do with the Gradle files.

Comment: @mayamanxoni please recheck this . You are changing values in file which is generated by Android Studio, so it is changed every time you build your project. All files inside build folders are generated and there is no need in changing them.

Instead you should put your values in values.xml under app->src->main->res->values

Comment: Adnan, I didn't change any file that is generated by Android Studio. I had to define "dp" size for every screen size, so I created dimens.xml for every activity.

Comment: Found something for you . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802679/android-studio-wont-remember-new-edits-and-automatically-reverts-to-old-versions